# Why cygwin 'ls -l' does not show me the file size in bytes?

Tags: cygwin

How can I configure cygwin to show file size in bytes when I do 'ls -l'?

I get size in bytes under ubuntu, but not in cygwin.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to get ls on Cygwin to show the file size in **bytes**. To do this you must set the block size to **1** (one).

```
ls -l --block-size=1
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1061794/kevin-hendrickson) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1061795/kevin-hendrickson). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ls -s --block-size=1k
```

and

```
ls -s --block-size=8k
```

Resource : http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg01189.html

Comment: And to make it work all the time, add in ~/.bashrc `alias ls='ls -s --blocksize=1k'` and then it will always work (after log out/back in that is)